# Performing an Operation On Grouped Pandas Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following information:

```
year  state     candidate        percvotes  electoral_votes  perc_evotes   vote_frac      vote_int
1976  ALABAMA   CARTER, JIMMY    55.727269       9            5.015454     0.015454         5
1976  ALABAMA   FORD, GERALD     42.614871       9            3.835338     0.835338         3
1976  ALABAMA   MADDOX, LESTER   0.777613        9            0.069985     0.069985         0
1976  ALABAMA  BUBAR, BENJAMIN   0.563808        9            0.050743     0.050743         0
1976  ALABAMA   HALL, GUS        0.165194        9            0.014867     0.014867         0
```

where `pervotes` is the percentage of the total votes cast the candidate received (calculated before), `electoral_votes` are the electoral college votes for that state, `perc_evotes` is the calculated percent of the electoral votes, and `vote_frac` and `vote_int` are the fraction and whole number part of the electoral votes earned respectively. This data repeats for each year of an election and then by state per year. The candidates each have a row for each state, and it is similar data.

What I want to do is allocate the leftover electoral votes to the candidate with the highest fraction. This number is different for each state and year. In this case there would be 1 leftover electoral vote (9 total votes and 5+3=8 are already allocated) and the remaining one will go to 'FORD, GERALD' since he has 0.85338 in the `vote_frac` column. Sometimes there are 2 or 3 left unallocated.

I have a solution that adds the data to a dictionary, but it is using `for` loops. I know there must be a better way to do this in a more "pandas" way. I have touched on `groupby` in this loop but I feel like I am not utilizing pandas to it's full potential.

My `for` loop:

```
results = {}
grouped = electdf.groupby(["year", "state"])                            
for key, group in grouped:
    year, state = key
    group['vote_remaining'] = group['electoral_votes'] - group['vote_int'].sum()
    remaining = group['vote_remaining'].iloc[0]
    top_fracs = group['vote_frac'].nlargest(remaining)
    group['total'] = (group['vote_frac'].isin(top_fracs)).astype(int) + group['vote_int'] 
    if year not in results:
        results[year] = {}                                     
    for candidate, evotes in zip(group['candidate'], group['total']):
        if candidate not in results[year] and evotes:
            results[year][candidate] = 0
        if evotes:
            results[year][candidate] += evotes
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an apply function which finds the available electoral votes, the amount of votes cast, and conditionally updates the max `'vote_frac'` row's `'vote_int'` column with the difference of available and cast votes:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': {0: 1976, 1: 1976, 2: 1976, 3: 1976, 4: 1976},
                   'state': {0: 'ALABAMA', 1: 'ALABAMA', 2: 'ALABAMA',
                             3: 'ALABAMA', 4: 'ALABAMA'},
                   'candidate': {0: 'CARTER, JIMMY', 1: 'FORD, GERALD',
                                 2: 'MADDOX, LESTER', 3: 'BUBAR, BENJAMIN',
                                 4: 'HALL, GUS'},
                   'percvotes': {0: 55.727269, 1: 42.614871, 2: 0.777613, 3: 0.563808,
                                 4: 0.165194},
                   'electoral_votes': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9, 3: 9, 4: 9},
                   'perc_evotes': {0: 5.015454, 1: 3.835338, 2: 0.069985,
                                   3: 0.050743, 4: 0.014867},
                   'vote_frac': {0: 0.015454, 1: 0.835338, 2: 0.069985,
                                 3: 0.050743, 4: 0.014867},
                   'vote_int': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}})


def apply_extra_e_votes(grp):
    # Get First Electoral Vote
    # (Assumes first row in group contains the
    #  correct number of electoral votes for the group)
    available_e_votes = grp['electoral_votes'].iloc[0]
    # Get the Sum of the vote_int column
    current_e_votes = grp['vote_int'].sum()
    # If there more available votes than votes cast
    if available_e_votes > current_e_votes:
        # Update the 'vote_int' column at the max value of 'vote_frac'
        grp.loc[
            grp['vote_frac'].idxmax(),
            'vote_int'
        ] += available_e_votes - current_e_votes  # (Remaining Votes)
    return grp


# Groupby and Apply Function
new_df = df.groupby(['year', 'state']).apply(apply_extra_e_votes)

# For Display
print(new_df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

| year | state | candidate | percvotes | electoral_votes | perc_evotes | vote_frac | vote_int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1976 | ALABAMA | CARTER, JIMMY | 55.727269 | 9 | 5.015454 | 0.015454 | 5 |
| 1976 | ALABAMA | FORD, GERALD | 42.614871 | 9 | 3.835338 | 0.835338 | 4 |
| 1976 | ALABAMA | MADDOX, LESTER | 0.777613 | 9 | 0.069985 | 0.069985 | 0 |
| 1976 | ALABAMA | BUBAR, BENJAMIN | 0.563808 | 9 | 0.050743 | 0.050743 | 0 |
| 1976 | ALABAMA | HALL, GUS | 0.165194 | 9 | 0.014867 | 0.014867 | 0 |